# Determing XPath to retrieve values in XML

Tags: xml, xpath

Please refer the sample XML below

```
<Actions>
    <Action>
        <Name>Forward</Name>
        <Value>Forward Assignment</Value>
        <panelID>Y0192_pnlForwad</panelID>
        <Status>Order Suspended</Status>
        <from>Shop</from>
        <to>Warehouse</to>
    </Action>
</Actions>
```

If I know the value of "from" node, how can I determine the corresponding value of "Name" and "Value" node using an XPath expression?

Comment: You want help on XPath query on how to retrieve such node? I am not sure I am clear here

Comment: You mean something like this `/Actions/Action[from='Shop']/*[self::Name or self::Value]` ?

Comment: You are right Tom. This is what I exactly meant. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: One quick question Tom although. Does it matter the location of the name and value nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I know the value of "from" node, how can I determine the
>   corresponding value of "Name" and "Value" node using an XPath
>   expression?

**Use**:

```
/*/Action[from='Shop']/*[self::Name or self::Value]
```

This selects any element named `Name` or named `Value`, whose parent is an `Action` child of the top element of the XML document, and (the `Action` parent) has a `from` child, whose string value is the string `"Shop"`.

**If you want the `Name` and `Value` selected (not together but) individually**, this can be done evaluting two XPath expressions:

```
/*/Action[from='Shop']/Name
```

and

```
/*/Action[from='Shop']/Value
```